# asp.netのグリッドビューで入力させたテキストにヒットした行だけを表示したい

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

asp.netのグリッドビューでテキストボックスに入力させた内容にヒットした行だけを表示したいです。
その際にできれば画面を更新したくないです。
どのようなアプローチが可能でしょうか？

Comment: 「画面を更新」とはPostBackのことでしょうか。

Comment: ASP.NET上で各セルにクラスを指定しておき、JavaScriptですべての`<tr>`について要素の値が条件に合致するかを判定して`display`スタイルを切り替える形になるのではないでしょうか。もしページをまたぐ必要があるのであれば、非同期ポストバックが必要になります。

Comment: コメントを受けて質問を立て直したなら、その旨を書かれては。
http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/22000/